# Changing curve modifier orientation

Tags: animation, instances

I'm creating a factory loop, but I cant change the orientation in certain point.

[image]

The method I'm using is pretty simple: an instanced mesh, following a curve trough the conveyor belt. I'm struggling trying to change the rotation when it takes the curve along the conveyor.

What should I do?

Thank you all in advice!

Comment: instead of using a mesh with the curve modifier you could use a follow path constraint on multiple duplicate instances. [Follow Path Constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html)

Comment: i hadn't any time to try it. today I did it, and it worked!!

Comment: thank you Leonardo!